# Can't access object property by array value

Tags: php, mysqli

I didnot understand why this is not working in PHP 7.0

```
$obj = mysqli_fetch_object(...);
if (is_object($obj)) { // OK
 echo $obj->name;
 // writes Hello
 $my_var = "name";
 echo $obj->$my_var; 
 // writes Hello
 $my_arr = array('test' => array('col' => 'name'));
 echo $obj->$my_arr['test']['col']; // <-- this didnot work
 // writes nothing :( 
}
```

Could I anyway to correct it?

Comment: Because `->` is executed before `[...]`.

Comment: How could I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->` is executed before `[]`, so your code is equivalent to:

```
echo ($obj->$my_arr)['test']['col'];
```

You can change that with `{}`:

```
echo $obj->{$my_arr['test']['col']};
```